# How do I aggregate data in R in a way that returns the entire row that satisfies the aggregation condition? [no dplyr]

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  FACTOR_VAR  INT_VAR
1     CAT          1
1     DOG          0
```

I want to aggregate by `ID` such that the resulting dataframe contains the *entire* row that satisfies my aggregate condition. So if I aggregate by the `max` of `INT_VAR`, I want to return the whole first row:

```
ID  FACTOR_VAR  INT_VAR
1     CAT          1
```

The following will not work because `FACTOR_VAR` is a factor:

```
new_data <- aggregate(data[,c("ID", "FACTOR_VAR", "INT_VAR")], by=list(data$ID), fun=max)
```

How can I do this? I know dplyr has a group by function, but unfortunately I am working on a computer for which downloading packages takes a long time. So I'm looking for a way to do this with just vanilla R.

Comment: Use `ave`  if you want to keep all the columns: `subset(df, as.logical(ave(INT_VAR, ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep all the columns, use `ave` instead :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(INT_VAR, ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` for this. If you want to retain all the columns, `merge` can be used with it.

```
merge(aggregate(INT_VAR ~ ID, data = df, max), df, all.x = T)

 #   ID INT_VAR FACTOR_VAR
 #1  1       1        CAT
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L), FACTOR_VAR = structure(1:2, .Label = c("CAT", "DOG"), class = "factor"), INT_VAR = 1:0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID)
  filter(INT_VAR == max(INT_VAR))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[INT_VAR == max(INT_VAR)], by = ID]
```